# Function to convert Python 2D list into 2D dictionary including mean and max calculations (ideally using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to write a function that takes a 2D list as an input, makes a mean and max calculation on the floats contained within the lists, and returns a 2D dictionary to then pretty print to the console.

The lists within the list of the input will always have a string at index 0 followed by a number of floats. Each list will be of equal length (same number of floats following the string heading).

I'd ideally like to try out pandas and/or numpy if possible.

As a small example, if my input was:

```
input_list = [["header_1", 56.0, 78.0, 100.0], ["header_2", 88.0, 99.0, 101.0]]
```

I'd like the function to return:

```
output_dict = {"header_1": {"mean": 78.0, "max": 100.0}, "header_2": {"mean": 96.0, "max": 101.0}}
```

Any help much appreciated! Thank you.

(Bonus points if it's possible for the function to return a table - otherwise I was planning to pretty print.)

EDIT: I realise that in some of the lists, there can be a string appearing instead of a float (by error), or missing data. In these scenarios, I would want to ignore the string or missing and process the max and mean calculations without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without pandas you can do something like this:

```py
def stats(input_list):
    output_dict = {}
    for item in input_list:
        header, values = item[0], item[1:]
        output_dict[header] = {
            "mean": sum(values)/len(values),
            "max": max(values)
        }
    output_table = pd.DataFrame(output_dict)
    return output_table
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works great. I realise that in some of the lists, there can be a string appearing instead of a float (by error), or missing data. In these scenarios, I would want to ignore the string or missing and process the max and mean calculations without them. Can you advise how I could handle this please? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your lists into a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame(data=[one_list[1:] for one_list in input_list], columns=[one_list[0] for one_list in input_list])
```

and then the mean and max calculations can be done by calling `data.mean()` and `data.max()`

Those two methods return a DataFrame with one column and which uses the previous column headings as their index. Then you just have to put it into a dict.

Comment: Thank you very much